# How can one become brahma/vishnu/shiv?

Tags: shiva, vishnu, puranas, brahma

I heard that one can become Indra if he does 1000 rajsuvi/ashwamedha yajna(not sure). But is there anywhere in shastras written how can one become one among tridevs?

Comment: Hanuman is future Brahma

Comment: Shiva and Vishnu no one can become

Comment: Why not?? It sounds like abrahamic then.

Comment: One cannot become Ishvara. One can become Brahman. The power of an enlightened Jiva will never be the same as Brahma, Vishnu or Shiva.

Comment: @PradipGangopadhyay sir, there is a story of brahma, vishnu and mahesh reaching a loka, kalipura, where millions of brahma, vishnu and mahesh were doing tapasya. So, there are millions like them. So, how can one not be like them? How can you say this?

Comment: What I said is the teaching.

Comment: @Rudra one Krishna became cows and gopalas when Brahma taked Krishna's cows and friends

Comment: @Rudra having strict rules doesn't make a religion abrahamic. That term refers to the cults originated among the descendants of Abraham.

Comment: How can you become what you already are? "Aham Brahmasmi," I am Brahman! "Shivoham," I am Shiva! Is it not so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Jiva cannot become Ishvara.

> Who is Ishvara? Janmadyasyayatah - "From whom is the birth,
> continuation, and dissolution of the universe," - He is Ishvara - "the
> Eternal, the Pure, the Ever-Free, the Almighty, the All-Knowing, the
> All-Merciful, the Teacher of all teachers"; and above all, Sa
> Ishvarahanirvachaniya-premasvarupah - "He the Lord is, of His own
> nature, inexpressible Love." These certainly are the definitions of a
> Personal God. Are there then two Gods - the "Not this, not this," the
> Sat-chit-ananda, the Existence-knowledge-Bliss of the philosopher, and
> this God of love of the Bhakta? No it is the same Sat-chit-ananda who
> is also the God of Love, the impersonal and personal in one. It has
> always to be understood that the Personal God worshipped by the Bhakta
> is not separate or different from Brahman. All is Brahman, the One
> without a second; only the Brahman, as unity or absolute, is too much
> of an abstraction to be loved and worshipped; so the Bhakta chooses
> the relative aspect of Brahman, that is Ishvara, the Supreme Ruler. **To
> use a simile: Brahman is as the clay or substance out of which an
> infinite variety of articles are fashioned. As clay, they are all one;
> but form or manifestation differentiates them. Before everyone of them
> was made, they all existed potentially in the clay, and, of course,
> they are identical substantially; but when formed, and so long as the
> form remains, they are separate and different;** **the clay-mouse can
> never become a clay-elephant, because, as manifestations, form alone
> makes them what they are, though as unformed clay they are all one.**
> Ishvara is the highest manifestation of the Absolute Reality, or in
> other words, the highest possible reading of the Absolute by the human
> mind. Creation is eternal and so also is Ishvara........Those who
> attain to that state where there is neither knower, nor knowable, nor
> knowledge, where there is neither I, nor thou, nor he, where there is
> neither subject, nor object, nor relation, "there, who is seen by
> whom?" - such persons have gone beyond everything to "where words
> cannot go nor mind", gone to where the Shrutis declare as "Not this,
> not this"; but for those who cannot, or will not reach this state,
> there will inevitably remain the triune vision of the one
> undifferentiated Brahman as nature, soul and the interpenetrating
> sustainer of both - Ishvara.

**The Complete Works of Swami Vivekananda III.37-42**